# Getting upcoming world wide releases from a database

Tags: mysql

From my database I want to get upcoming world wide release dates for an itemId along with the platformIds.

If I have a table that looks like this and the current date is 2014-05-14

```
+--------+------------+-------------+-----------+
| itemId | platformId | releaseDate | countryId |
+--------+------------+-------------+-----------+
|    1   |    NULL    |  2014-05-11 |     1     |
+--------+------------+-------------+-----------+
|    2   |    NULL    |  2014-05-14 |     2     |
+--------+------------+-------------+-----------+
|    2   |    NULL    |  2014-05-15 |     1     |
+--------+------------+-------------+-----------+
|    2   |    NULL    |  2014-05-15 |     3     |
+--------+------------+-------------+-----------+
|    3   |      1     |  2014-10-15 |     1     |
+--------+------------+-------------+-----------+
|    3   |      2     |  2014-10-15 |     1     |
+--------+------------+-------------+-----------+
|    3   |      1     |  2014-10-25 |     2     |
+--------+------------+-------------+-----------+
|    1   |    NULL    |  2012-03-02 |     7     |
+--------+------------+-------------+-----------+
|    4   |    NULL    |  2014-05-19 |     1     |
+--------+------------+-------------+-----------+
```

I want my output to be:

```
+--------+------------+----------------+-----------+
| itemId | platformId | releaseDate    | countryId |
+--------+------------+----------------+-----------+
| 4      | NULL       | May 19th, 2014 | 1         |
+--------+------------+----------------+-----------+
| 3      | 1,2        | Oct 15th, 2014 | 1         |
+--------+------------+----------------+-----------+
```

This is my query so far:

```
SELECT
  itemId,
  IF( DAY(releaseDate) = 00, 
        IF( MONTH(releaseDate) = 00, 
            YEAR(releaseDate),
            DATE_FORMAT(releaseDate, '%b %Y')
        ), 
        DATE_FORMAT(releaseDate, '%b %D, %Y')
    ) AS releaseDate,
  GROUP_CONCAT(platformId) AS platforms,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT countryId) AS countryIds
FROM
  releaseDates
WHERE releaseDate > "2014-05-14"
GROUP BY itemId, releaseDate
ORDER BY 
    YEAR(releaseDate), 
    MONTH(releaseDate) = 00 AND DAY(releaseDate) = 00,
    DAY(releaseDate) = 00,
    MONTH(releaseDate),
    DAY(releaseDate)
```

I've created a SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56d3ec/2)

Basically what I need is upcoming release dates for platformIds and an itemId that have never been together before. If there are 2 platformIds with an itemId and one of the platformIds have already been with the itemId then only the new platformId should be displayed with the itemId.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56d3ec/18

Comment: @Mihai That won't work if you have another itemId with NULL as the platformId that has its first releaseDate after 2014-05-14

Comment: I've never seen a date like this `'2014-10-00'` before.

Comment: I use it to store release dates for when you only know the month of the year but not the day. How would you store that?

Comment: @ypercube Yes, it stores it as `2014-10-00`. That's not really the problem here so I changed that row in my example.

Comment: Yeah my bad. I had forgotten that they are actually stored in this (insane) way.

Comment: @ypercube What's "insane" about it?

Comment: I'm not talking about your question but whether this kind of non-valid dates should be allowed to be stored in a DATE datatype column by the DBMS. You may get unpredictable results if by accident you use functions like DATE_ADD or DATE_SUB with the non-valid dates and your queries get to be quite complicated.

Comment: I know that modelling incomplete information (i.e. "I know the year but not the month", "only month but not exact date") is far from trivial. You either result in a complicated (normalized) design with quite normal looking and easy to write queries or a simple design with very complicated and difficult to debug queries. No easy solution for this problem.